# Restrictions of distributions

Tags: functional-analysis, distribution-theory

Is it possible to have a distribution $u\in \mathcal{D}'(\mathbb{R})$ such that the restriction of $u$ to $(0,\infty)$ is $\frac{1}{x}$ and the restriction of $u$ to $(-\infty,0)$ is $0$?

It seems to me that the answer should be 'no', but I couldn't figure how to prove it.

Answer (score 2):

It is possible: define $u\in\mathcal D'(\mathbb R)$ by $u(\phi)=\int_0^\infty \frac 1 x (\phi(x)-\phi(0)e^{-x}) dx$.

Note that for any test function $\phi$, the function $x\mapsto \phi(x)-\phi(0)e^{-x}$ is smooth and sends zero to zero (and has compact support), which implies that $(\phi(x)-\phi(0)e^{-x})/x$ can be integrated on $(0,\infty)$. (Thanks Julián Aguirre for pointing out the problem with just integrating $\phi(x)/x$.)

$u$ is clearly linear. To show that $u$ is a distribution, consider a sequence $\phi_n\to 0$ in $\mathcal D(\mathbb R)$. The support of the functions $\phi_n$ is contained in some interval $[-K,K]$ (and we can assume $K\geq 1$). By integration by parts we have
$$u(\phi_n)=\lim_{\epsilon\to 0^+}\int_\epsilon^K \frac 1 x (\phi_n(x)-\phi_n(0)e^{-x}) dx
=-\lim_{\epsilon\to 0^+}\int_\epsilon^K \log(x) (\phi_n'(x)+\phi_n(0)e^{-x}) dx$$

Note $\int_0^K|\log x|dx\leq K\log K+1$. Thus
$$|u(\phi_n)|\leq (K\log K+1) \max_{0\leq x\leq K}(|\phi_n'(x)|+|\phi_n(0)|)\to 0$$

Comment: Note that $1/x$ is not locally integrable at $x=0$, so that $\phi(x)/x$ is not integrable if $\phi(0)\ne0$.

Comment: @JuliánAguirre: thanks for pointing out the problem.

Comment: Thanks, but I still have one silly question: why is $u$ a distribution? i.e. how can I find an appropriate bound to $|u(\phi)|$ given a compact set $K\subseteq \mathbb{R}$?

Comment: @Dist: I've added an argument bounding $|u(\phi)|$.

Comment: I'm probably missing something silly again, but why does $u(\phi)=\int_0^\infty \frac{\phi(x)}{x}$ for $\phi$ with compact support?

Comment: @Dist: if you mean why is the restriction of $u$ to $(0,\infty)$ the distribution $1/x$, then it's because a test function on $(0,\infty)$ gets extended to $\mathbb R$ by sending $(-\infty,0]$ to zero, and so the $\phi(0)$ term is zero.

Comment: Oh, of course! Thanks.

Comment: @ColinMcQuillan: Your function $x\mapsto \phi(x) - \phi(0)e^{-x}$ doesn't have compact support. So, in the proof of the continuity, integrating upto $K$ is not sufficient, but this can be repaired.